# Comparator in Linked Lists

Tags: java, linked-list, comparator

I'm writing a program that is a linked list, trying to insert something in order and I've used this in my code but it keeps saying that it's a NullPointerException, and I'm not sure why.

```
 public SortedLinkedList<T> add(T element) {
 Node insert = new Node(element);
```

Then I check to make sure curr isn't null.

```
if (comparator.compare(curr.data, insert.data) <= 0 
    && comparator.compare(curr.next.data, insert.data) > 0){
```

Comment: You should be checking whether `curr` has a next Node before accessing it.

Answer (score 1):

> Then I check to make sure curr isn't null.

The code you've posted isn't checking to see if `curr` is null, it is doing a comparison, and probably trying to do a comparison on an Object that does not exist.

You should check to make sure that the next element (`curr.next`) in your linked list exists before you try to access it.

Answer (score 1):

I dont't know what's the body of `comparator.compare`, but it there's no null check in that method, you should do something like this.

```
if (curr != null && curr.data!=null && comparator.compare(curr.data, insert.data) <= 0 
&& comparator.compare(curr.next.data, insert.data) > 0){
```